# Pandas dataframe with nan in Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, null

How can I get/select nan in Index of a Dataframe. I have made a MultiIndex dataframe with 4 levels in which 1st level has some nan values which i want in another dataframe

i tried many methods of getting null values but none of those seems to work with index as null
heres an example
Fruit and color are my index and i want to get those rows with nan values

```
               Count    Price
Fruit   Color       
Apple   Red     3       $1.29
nan     Green   9       $0.99
Pear    Red     25      $2.59
nan     Green   26      $2.79
Lime    Green   99      $0.39
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test first level of `MultiIndex` extracted by [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`Index.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isna.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df[df.index.get_level_values(0).isna()]
print (df2)
             Count  Price
Fruit Color              
NaN   Green      9  $0.99
      Green     26  $2.79
```

Or get [`MultiIndex.codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.codes.html) and compare by `-1`:

```
df2 = df[df.index.codes[0] == -1]
print (df2)
             Count  Price
Fruit Color              
NaN   Green      9  $0.99
      Green     26  $2.79
```

Comment: @rajsx - OK, so what is `print (df.index.get_level_values(0).unique().tolist())` ?

Comment: i tried nan, nat, none as well none of these works and i cant actually find a solution i can see the dataframe with nan values but can't select and extract those to another dataframe

Comment: `print (df4.index.get_level_values(0).unique().tolist())
['AMERICA', 'Africa', 'China', 'Europe', 'Far East', 'India', 'ME', 'MED', 'Russia', 'SEA', 'South America', nan]`

Comment: @rajsx - Can you test `df2 = df[df.index.get_level_values(0).isna()]` ?

Comment: Oh thanks a lot this worked `df2 = df[df.index.get_level_values(0).isna()]`

Comment: please add this to the answer so i can mark it as answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204551/discussion-between-rajsx-and-jezrael).